# Hot swapp vs Hot Code replace, what's the difference?

Tags: java, eclipse, hotswap, hot-code-replace

Im new to debbuging in java and i'm hearing these two terms used "Hot code replace" and "Hot swapping", from what i understood "hot swapping" is a feature in the actual jvm that can only replace code inside a method body.

Whereas "hot code replace" is being used by eclipse to replace every change that is being made (including classes and methods redefinition) in a JEE server (jboss, wildfly ,etc...).

So i just want to confirm if this is true or are these 2 terms exacly the same thing ?
And what's the exact technologie being used in eclipse to do this task, is it a plugin or something else ?

Answer (score 2):

The two terms **mean the same** thing.

[***HotSwap*** is the **Java internal** name of this feature of the Java debugger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/enhancements1.4.html#hotswap), which **in Eclipse** is more descriptively referred to as ***hot code replace*** (see e.g. [Java Debug Preferences](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-06/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/debug/ref-debug.htm?cp=1_4_4_0_4)).

See also: [Wikipedia - Hot swapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_swapping#Software)